# Drush installed but all commands could not be found

Tags: drush

I have drush installed on a remote server and was able to successfully run commands this morning, however I tried executing `Drush Self-Update` and got a permission error probably because I don't have sudo rights etc and now any drush commands I try run return the error `The drush command 'drush_command_here' could not be found.`
when I run `which drush` it returns `/usr/bin/drush` so I know its installed + other users on the server can run drush commands without issue.
I tried adding the drush alias in my .bashrc file like this `alias = '/usr/bin/drush'` and also tried using the alias pointing to usr/share/drush but no luck.
[image: Error msg]

Comment: What's the drush version? (`drush --version`) This of course sounds like a permission issue, how was Drush installed in the first place?

Comment: drush --version gives 4.5
we used apt-get to install drush on this server. The pear install method reported some error.

Comment: The version is pretty outdated, anything below 6.0 is unsupported at this time. The pear install will work but sometimes it's behind a little and you have to do the channel register. The recommended way to install is via Composer now. You can see the install methods here: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ and I would just reinstall with those instructions and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up uninstalling and re-installing drush and seems to have fixed my problem. Thanks.